# good-py.appspot.com mirror blocked in China?

Tags: python, plone, zope

According to IRC report, good-py.appspot.com service may be blocked in China.

This makes Plone / Zope development somewhat troublesome.

Is it possible to set-up mirror/proxy for this service easily?

Comment: I guess you shouldn't have tagged it 'python'...

Comment: @aus regardless mirrors and proxies are basic internet 101 not programming

Comment: It's not about programming - it's about how _we_, Plone/Zope, developers are to set up our buildouts to work in China.  It's a perfectly good development question, that has been closed by people who have no apparent understanding of the environment.  In any case, proxies are not "basic internet".  They're beyond the knowledge of either the average Internet user or the average developer.

Comment: You can download the output of goodpy and put that file locally instead of as an `extends = url` line. Easy enough, right?